# Variable shift register in verilog

Tags: verilog

I want to design a variable shift  register to shift to the right as follows:

```
module sr(N,int,out);

  input [2:0] N;
  input [7:0] in;
  output [7:0] out;

  assign out={N'b0,input[7,N]}

endmodule
```

But unfortunately, Verilog doesn't allow this kind of writing. N should be constant.
Any idea on how to get shift iterations from input?

Comment: I think it's not allowed because it causes an exponential explosion in required amount of logic as the parameters get larger. Do you need this for the general case, or just for that particular small example? For a 3 bit N it would be easy to just write a switch statement.

Comment: @Tim - just because the logic is big, doesn't mean it shouldn't be allowed though :)

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want a barrel shifter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7543592/verilog-barrel-shifter

Comment: Your original code has a syntax error (input[7,0]) as well as a bunch of mismatched names. See my answer for corrections.

Comment: yea this is a dummy code, just to show the concept.

Answer (score 6):

Verilog has a right shift operator so you can simply write:

```
assign out = in >> N;
```

The extra bits are automatically filled with zeros.

Comment: yes this is correct but the execution time of this type of shift is double of : assign out={[N'b0,in[7:N]}. but here N should be constant

Answer (score 3):

If the sizes of `in` and `out` are really fixed at 8 bits, here is one simple way to do it:

```
module sr(N, in, out);

  input  [2:0] N;
  input  [7:0] in;
  output [7:0] out;

  assign out = (N == 7) ? {7'b0, in[7:7]} : 
               (N == 6) ? {6'b0, in[7:6]} : 
               (N == 5) ? {5'b0, in[7:5]} : 
               (N == 4) ? {4'b0, in[7:4]} : 
               (N == 3) ? {3'b0, in[7:3]} : 
               (N == 2) ? {2'b0, in[7:2]} : 
               (N == 1) ? {1'b0, in[7:1]} : 
                                 in[7:0];

endmodule
```

This could also be coded using a case statement inside an `always` block, like this:

```
  reg [7:0] out_reg;
  assign out = out_reg;

  always @(N or in) begin
    case (N)
      7 : out_reg <= {7'b0, in[7:7]};
      6 : out_reg <= {6'b0, in[7:6]};
      5 : out_reg <= {5'b0, in[7:5]};
      4 : out_reg <= {4'b0, in[7:4]};
      3 : out_reg <= {3'b0, in[7:3]};
      2 : out_reg <= {2'b0, in[7:2]};
      1 : out_reg <= {1'b0, in[7:1]};
      0 : out_reg <=        in[7:0];
    endcase
  end
```

If you don't want to write out all the values you can use a `for` loop.  I'm not an expert on how the synthesis tools handle this but this (or something similar) should synthesize okay.

```
  always @(N or in) begin
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i = i + 1) begin
      if (i+N < 8) begin
        out_reg[i] <= in[i+N];
      end else begin
        out_reg[i] <= 1'b0;
      end
    end
  end
```

One advantage of coding it using a loop is it is less prone to cut-n-paste typos.

More importantly, if you want to make the module support generic bit-widths of the inputs and outputs, you can do so using a `parameter` on the module and a similar loop for the assignments.

Comment: tanx dwikle, I like the first code. I have at least 9 inputs, and 9 Ns. it means a crowded code. but seems there is no other choice