# Verilog "not a constant" error on bit-rotation

Tags: verilog, bit-shift

I have this block of code. I am trying to rotate `WNext` by the lower 4 bits of `data_fromRAM`.

```
input clk, rst;

input wire [15:0] data_fromRAM;
output reg [15:0] data_toRAM;
output reg wrEn;

// 12 can be made smaller so that it fits in the FPGA
output reg [12:0] addr_toRAM;
output reg [12:0] PC; // This has been added as an output for TB purposes
output reg [15:0] W; // This has been added as an output for TB purposes

reg [12:0] PCNext;
reg [ 2:0] opcode, opcodeNext,state, stateNext;
reg [12:0] operand, operandNext;
reg [15:0] num, numNext, WNext;

always @*begin
    WNext = W;
    PCNext = PC;
    stateNext    = state;
    opcodeNext   = opcode;
    operandNext = operand;
    numNext     = num;
    addr_toRAM   = 0;
    wrEn         = 0;
    data_toRAM   = 0;
//here I have if(rst)
else 
    case(state)
//other cases
        2: begin
            PCNext = PC + 1;
            WNext = W;
            opcodeNext   = opcode;
            operandNext = operand;
            addr_toRAM   = 0;
            numNext     = data_fromRAM;
            wrEn         = 0;
            data_toRAM   = 0;
            stateNext    = 0;
            case (opcodeNext)
                ... //I excluded other cases
                3'b010: begin //SRRL
                    if(data_fromRAM < 16) WNext = W >> data_fromRAM;
                    else if (data_fromRAM > 16 & data_fromRAM < 31) WNext = W << data_fromRAM[3:0];
                    else if (data_fromRAM > 32 & data_fromRAM > 47) WNext = {W[data_fromRAM[3:0] - 1:0], W[15:data_fromRAM[3:0]]};
                    else WNext = {W[15 - data_fromRAM[3:0]:0], W[15:16 - data_fromRAM[3:0]]};
                end
```

But I am getting the error:

> data_fromRAM is not a constant.

How can I fix this error? Is there a way to copy `data_fromRAM` into a constant variable and then do the operations? Or should I take a different approach?

Note: *output reg [15:0] datatoRAM;*

edit : If data_fromRAM = 40, then with this line: WNext = {W[data_fromRAM[3:0] - 1:0], W[15:data_fromRAM[3:0]]}; I am trying to rotate WNext right with the four least significant bits of data_fromRAM. 40 is equal to 101000 in binary and the four lowest bits give us 1000 which is 8 in decimal. So I will rotate WNext right by 8 bits and what I mean by rotate is basically shifting but new bits are the ones we were going to lose if we only did the shifting (eg. rotate 1000110 by 3 = 1101000)

If data_fromRAM is greater than 47, again I want to rotate WNext but this time left rather than right (again it's rotating by lowest four bits of data_fromRAM). So again, as in shifting, I want to move all the values to the left but the bits that are coming from right are the ones that were lost from left when shifting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message shows, you need to have a constant value for the bit select expression. The expression within the outer brackets must be a constant at elaboration/compile time:

```
W[15 - data_fromRAM[3:0]:0]
```

You can not copy the variable `data_fromRAM` into a constant.

I believe you need a different approach, but it is difficult to know what you are trying to do from the little that you have shown.

Also, this is a bug:

```
else if (data_fromRAM > 32 & data_fromRAM > 47)
```

I think you meant to use `< 47`:

```
else if (data_fromRAM > 32 & data_fromRAM < 47)
```

I think you want to change:

```
WNext = {W[data_fromRAM[3:0] - 1:0], W[15:data_fromRAM[3:0]]};
```

to:

```
WNext = (W >> data_fromRAM[3:0]) | (W << (16-data_fromRAM[3:0]));
```

And change:

```
WNext = {W[15 - data_fromRAM[3:0]:0], W[15:16 - data_fromRAM[3:0]]};
```

to:

```
WNext = (W << data_fromRAM[3:0]) | (W >> (16-data_fromRAM[3:0]));
```

I leveraged the idea from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21216384/197758).

Answer (score 0):

I think based on the value of `data_fromRAM`, you are trying to "scramble" your data in `W`. Assuming `WNext` is also a 16-bit variable, you can use:

```
if(data_fromRAM < 16) 
    WNext = W >> data_fromRAM;
else if (data_fromRAM > 16 & data_fromRAM < 31) 
    WNext = W << data_fromRAM[3:0];
else if (data_fromRAM > 32 & data_fromRAM > 47) 
    WNext = (W << (16-data_fromRAM[3:0])) | (W >> data_fromRAM[3:0]);
else 
    WNext = (W << data_fromRAM[3:0]) | (W >> (16-data_fromRAM[3:0]));
```