# Best way to describe in Verilog

Tags: verilog

I have two input vectors

```
wire [4:0] pow;
wire [12:0] number;
```

and one output vector

```
wire [43:0] result;
```

As a result,

```
result = number * (2 ^ pow)
```

in programming it will be equivalent of shifting `number` `pow` times left. What could be the fastest and least consuming circuit for this task, and how to describe it in Verilog?

**Edit:** I want to emphasize that question is not only about how to put what I need into Verilog, but also explain what happens behind in synthesis. If writing `result = number << pow;` as @dave_59 advised causes allocation of thousands of wires and logic elements, I would probably consider synchronous sequential shifter.

**Edit1:** What I need may be implemented by barrel shifter explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7543745/1468850), but it does not detail how much resources it will take in addition to second size of `data_in`.

Comment: I don't know about Verilog, but raising a number to a power isn't equivalent to shifting the number to the left.

Comment: OMG I am sorry, made a mistake, I edited the question

Answer (score 1):

Use a left shift

```
result = number << pow;
```

Comment: Is it immediate operation (as no clock is involved) and which circuit it is synthesized into?

Comment: Clock involvement may be dependent on your actual hardware. And in any case for shifting clock would be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I finished implementation of the clone of shifter using vector part-selects, bus size of 31 bits and shifting part of 9 bits added 83 logic elements and 86 combinational functions. I think it is comparable to putting conditional operator.